# Load XML File without AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I want to load a static XML file into HTML and process it without a AJAX request.

I dont want to make an AJAX request because, when that html file is viewed without a webserver (which is a requirement for us),

> Chrome throws following error and it stops playback for us. 
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://C:/project/abcd.xml. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> IE11 doesn't throw any error, but it never loads the file.

Is there any way to add this static XML file as part of a tag like script or link? 
Once loaded I want to parse the XML using JQuery.

Comment: place the xml in the same folder as the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no you can't.

You cant load the XML into a web page without either using JS/AJAX or a server side language (which you don't have without a web server). This applies of course to the intention of post-processing the data in the HTML-page using jQuery.

The AJAX request is stopped due to the fact that browsers adhere to the "same origin policy" (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can't work around that without either running a local web server or putting the files onto a public web server.

Comment: @AMS Well I have hard to see how to satisfy the requirement " Once loaded I want to parse the XML using JQuery." then...?